# _exception (exception: failed to load tickets) flutter API

Tags: windows, flutter

_exception (exception: failed to load tickets) flutter API

Here is my flutter:

```
Future<List<Ticket>> fetchTickets() async {
    final response =
        await http.get(Uri.parse('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/tickets'));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final jsonResult = json.decode(response.body);
      final ticketList = jsonResult['data'] as List<dynamic>;
      return ticketList.map((json) => Ticket.fromJson(json)).toList();
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load tickets');
    }
  }
```